# Cortex-M0 Hardfault Handler does not get called after changing it

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, keil, bare-metal

i am using an using an STM32f0 and getting into Hardfault. My IDE is Keil MDK. I was trying to find the roots of it, so every approach i find in the web (mostly for M3/M4) tells to unwind the stack. see e.g.:
[arm.com](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/system/f/embedded-forum/4749/error-hard-fault-handler)

For this I logically need to change the basic implementation of the HardFault Handler.

```
HardFault_Handler\
                PROC
                MRS r7,MSP
                EXPORT  HardFault_Handler              [WEAK]
                B       .
                ENDP
```

after adding the line `MRS r7,MSP` the HardHandler does not get called any more and the application keeps running.

The same happens when I try to implement my own HardFault_handler in c.

I have no clue. Thanks in advance!

greetings

Comment: Hi, it is a Cortex-M0. And i am building for Cortex-M0. The Application worked well for months until recently. So i am assuming the setup is right. 
I get a HardFault. i change the HardFault_Handler_Code only. I dont get a HardFault anymore. This is what seems fishy to me.

Comment: what does your vector table look like after linking?  How are you triggering the hardfault?

Comment: How can i check what the vector table looks like after linking (in Keil)?